# Programs available for generating ishihara plates

Tags: image, testing, graphics, colors

I've been attempting to make my own ishihara plate however when I rasterize to grayscale its clear my attempt did not work.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on programs available to "ishihara-ize" an image. My goals was to make up a checkerboard (of different colour combos i.e red and green) and when grayscale the image no longer held the square boundaries of the checkers on the board.

I appreciate any help thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add pictures of what you want and what you already tried (and failed) if you want people to be interested in your question ... also show us the code

Comment: I've been using adobe illustrator to attempt to generate the image after downloading an ishihara substrate from http://www.creatogether.com/wp-content/uploads/IPG/ however choose the correct saturation of each colour for each individual circle has been challenging